# Setting parameters for Python based digit puller

Tags: python, syntax, parameters, sys

I'm trying to make a Python utility that will pull digits from the head or tail of a string. I would like to make the # of digits to pull the second parameter given in the scripts syntax. ex: "script.py string -2" to pull the last 2 digits from the string resulting in "ng"
Below is my code

## /usr/bin/python

import sys
print sys.argv[1] [sys.argv[2]:]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It doesn't work. It throws up an error when I try to use sys.argv[2]
it will only work if it is set up like this
print sys.argv[1] [-3:]
but that number needs to be a variable because it won't be the same every time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you weren't changing the type of the second argument to an integer. By default, the `sys.argv` enteries are strings. If you want to use them as integers, use `int`.

```
import sys

print sys.argv[1][int(sys.argv[2]):]
```